# How many linear matroids are transversal

Tags: co.combinatorics, matroid-theory

It is known that almost all matroids are not linear matroids (a.k.a. not representable matroids). This was shown by Nelson:

[arXiv: Almost all matroids are non-representable](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.04288)

A transversal matroid is a certain type of linear matroid with various equivalent definitions. Transerval matroids are linear matroids, and they can always be represented over any infinite field. See the survey of Bonin for a nice introduction:

[AN INTRODUCTION TO TRANSVERSAL MATROIDS](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/shortcourse/2011/TransversalNotes.pdf)

My question is how rare are transversal matroids amongst all linear matroids? I am most interested in real representable matroids, but interested in any results enumerating or estimating how many transversal matroids there are.